# Sequelize sum of column with time

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

i'm new and i'm running into the SEQUELIZE orm.
I use it with mysql,

I have to do the sum of the time column
the data contained are of time value e.g. 01:05:00

I need to get the sum of the time column.
I tried searching but couldn't find anything that can help me
can you help me
is it possible to do this using sequelize?
thank you all

I searched the internet but to no avail
I don't have the slightest idea of how to do it and if it can be done

Comment: Can you show a desired query (SQL) and a result?

Answer (score 0):

The select in **mysql** is as follows
works correctly and the result obtained is:

```
select SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( tempoVolo) ) ) from  tblName
```

and the **results** is:

```
48:53:00.000000
```